# For loop with enumerate - index position

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing, enumerate

I have a solution to erase duplicates from a list. In this solution is used an enumerate.

```py
def myfunc(list_input):
    list_output=[]
    for num1, num2 in enumerate(list_input):
        if num2 not in list_input[0:num1]:
            list_output.append(num2)
    return list_output

print(myfunc([1,1,2,3])) --> ,[1,2,3,]
```

However, I do not undersatand in which way we should read the index position for our enumerate.

What is the position for each interaction in `list_input[0:num1]`, having in consideration that we have started the `for` loop with a `num1, num2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enumerate iterates over an iterable (in this cause `list_input`), and with each iteration sets the first value (in this case `num1`) to the current index, and the second value (in this case `num2`) to the value of the iterable at this index.

For example, on first iteration, `num1 == 0` as the iteration begins at the zeroeth element, and `num2 == 1` as `list_input[0] == 1`. `list_input[0:num1] == []` so nothing is in it and therefore the value is appended to the outputs.

On second iteration, the index has incremented by one and so `num1 == 1`. `list_input[0:num1] == [1]` now, and as `num2` is in `[1]`, the value is not appended to the output list.

Comment: Thank you! It was very clear for me. sorry for the non editing post, it was my first interaction at stackoverflow.

Comment: Not a problem, I hope you got the help you needed! Please try and remember to upvote answers you find useful, and accept the answer that most accurately resolves your issue so that people know the issue is solved and no more effort is required to be spent on a solution!

Answer (score 0):

The question needs to be elaborated on, and please do fix the formatting. But if I understand correctly, if you want to remove duplicates and have a need for the positioning or index of each element (number) of the non-duplicates you make use of enumerate() and possibly do something like this:

```
nums = [1,1,3,5,7,9]
newlist = []
for num in nums:
  if num not in newlist:
    newlist.append(num)
for index, nums in enumerate(newlist):
  print("Index positioning: %s and Number at respective index is: %s" % (index,nums))
```

Output:

```
Index positioning: 0 and Number at respective index is: 1
Index positioning: 1 and Number at respective index is: 3
Index positioning: 2 and Number at respective index is: 5
Index positioning: 3 and Number at respective index is: 7
Index positioning: 4 and Number at respective index is: 9
```